# How we store data for a desktop application?

Tags: desktop-client

I'm new to developing desktop application and i don't know how this job is done.
When i deliver a desktop application to a client, should i install database on his PC like MYSQL?
is there a common way in this job to store data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is it all depends on what you need to store and what you need to do with it!

Some Common Options:

- Store a few settings: Put them in the registry
- Store several settings: Put them in an ini or json file
- Store Miscellaneous Information: Text File/Json/XML/your own format
- Store & query **a lot** of information **all** with a **consistent** structure: Use proprietary format or a database.

Even in the last case the question remains about whether to use a central database or to put one on the users machine.